# Get next Date from day hour:minutes

Tags: java

I am trying to get the next Date that match a date format, like getting next Date that match "1 10:00" (format: u HH:mm).

**Example**: If we are **Tuesday June 2 - 22:00** (for example), I want to get **Sunday June 7 - 10:00** as a Date object (because it does match "1 10:00" format)

EDIT: It was "u" instead of "F", sorry !

Comment: The usual comment at this point is: please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Format `F` stands for day  of week in month, so what is it you'd like to do exactly?

Comment: June 7th is not the next date to have 1 in its F field. June 3rd is. June 2nd is the first Tuesday of June, hence its F field is 1. June 3rd is the first Wednesday in June, hence its F field is also 1.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand good your question, this will do the trick. Basically adding 1 minute to current date until you find your desired date by its format.

You'd want to set a safest condition than true.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = new Date("06/02/2015 10:00");
calendar.setTime(date);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("F HH:mm");
while (true) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    if (sdf.format(calendar.getTime()).equals(sdf.format(date))) {
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
        break;
    }
}
```

This prints: 
Wed Jun 03 10:00:00 VET 2015 ... and 1440 minutes were added.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found a solution myself :

```
public static Date getNextDate(SimpleDateFormat format, String value) {
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(value);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        int diff = date.getDay() - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if (!(diff > 0)) {
            diff += 7;
        }
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, diff);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, date.getHours());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, date.getMinutes());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, date.getSeconds());

        return calendar.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

It will return the next date that match my format. I use deprecated methods but I will fix it asap.

Thanks for helping anyway !